# Long-Term Government Bond Yields

Tags: data, bond-yields

On the Federal Reserve of St. Louis FRED website we can find the 10-year government bond yields: https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/IRLTLT01USM156N.txt.

I chose monthly frequency and percent units. I'm wondering if the yields are quoted annually even though they have a monthly frequency.

Comment: As a general practice, the yields are quoted as an annual number indeed. I cross-checked the numbers in your link and they are indeed annual numbers. even if sourced / downloaded monthly, weekly or daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the quotes are annually. You can cross-check with these:
http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/data.htm